# Flutter Execute Method so long the button pressed

Tags: android, button, material-design, flutter, gesturedetector

I want to execute a method while a user is pressing down on a button. In pseudocode:

```
while (button.isPressed) {
  executeCallback();
}
```

In other words, the `executeCallback` method should fire repeatedly as long as the user is pressing down on the button, and stop firing when the button is released. How can I achieve this in Flutter?

Comment: so whats wrong with `GestureLongPressCallback onLongPress` property?

Comment: The Problem that onLongPress has been triggered After the press Operation but i need during the press Operatoin

Comment: it makes little sense: if you just make a normal quick press (meaning you release your finger in a short time) how could you get long click then?

Comment: Exactly that what i need i need the method will be excuted so long that the finger on the button

Comment: The Idea is about forword Button in Music player and i need to seek the song forword when the user is clicking on Button

Comment: forword? you mean forward? even though, i still dont get what you really want to achieve...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179245/discussion-between-doctordoom-and-pskink).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use a `Listener` and a stateful widget. I also introduced a slight delay after every loop:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  bool _buttonPressed = false;
  bool _loopActive = false;

  void _increaseCounterWhilePressed() async {
    // make sure that only one loop is active
    if (_loopActive) return;

    _loopActive = true;

    while (_buttonPressed) {
      // do your thing
      setState(() {
        _counter++;
      });

      // wait a bit
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200));
    }

    _loopActive = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Center(
        child: Listener(
          onPointerDown: (details) {
            _buttonPressed = true;
            _increaseCounterWhilePressed();
          },
          onPointerUp: (details) {
            _buttonPressed = false;
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange, border: Border.all()),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Text('Value: $_counter'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: That is excatly what i need

Comment: Please also handle `onPointerCancel` ;)

Answer (score 16):

A simpler way, without the listener, is as follows:

```dart
  GestureDetector(
      child: InkWell(
        child: Icon(Icons.skip_previous_rounded),
        onTap: widget.onPrevious,
      ),
      onLongPressStart: (_) async {
        isPressed = true;
        do {
          print('long pressing'); // for testing
          await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
        } while (isPressed);
      },
      onLongPressEnd: (_) => setState(() => isPressed = false),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Building on the solution from [ThinkDigital](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2880055/thinkdigital), my observation is that `InkWell` contains all the events necessary to do this without an extra `GestureDetector` (I find that the `GestureDetector` interferes with the ink animation on long press). Here's a control I implemented for a pet project that fires its event with a decreasing delay when held (this is a rounded button with an icon, but anything using `InkWell` will do):

```dart
/// A round button with an icon that can be tapped or held
/// Tapping the button once simply calls [onUpdate], holding
/// the button will repeatedly call [onUpdate] with a
/// decreasing time interval.
class TapOrHoldButton extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Update callback
  final VoidCallback onUpdate;

  /// Minimum delay between update events when holding the button
  final int minDelay;

  /// Initial delay between change events when holding the button
  final int initialDelay;

  /// Number of steps to go from [initialDelay] to [minDelay]
  final int delaySteps;

  /// Icon on the button
  final IconData icon;

  const TapOrHoldButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.onUpdate,
      this.minDelay = 80,
      this.initialDelay = 300,
      this.delaySteps = 5,
      required this.icon})
      : assert(minDelay <= initialDelay,
            "The minimum delay cannot be larger than the initial delay"),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _TapOrHoldButtonState createState() => _TapOrHoldButtonState();
}

class _TapOrHoldButtonState extends State<TapOrHoldButton> {
  /// True if the button is currently being held
  bool _holding = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var shape = CircleBorder();
    return Material(
      color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor,
      shape: shape,
      child: InkWell(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Icon(
            widget.icon,
            color:
                Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1?.color ?? Colors.white70,
            size: 36,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => _stopHolding(),
        onTapDown: (_) => _startHolding(),
        onTapCancel: () => _stopHolding(),
        customBorder: shape,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _startHolding() async {
    // Make sure this isn't called more than once for
    // whatever reason.
    if (_holding) return;
    _holding = true;

    // Calculate the delay decrease per step
    final step =
        (widget.initialDelay - widget.minDelay).toDouble() / widget.delaySteps;
    var delay = widget.initialDelay.toDouble();

    while (_holding) {
      widget.onUpdate();
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay.round()));
      if (delay > widget.minDelay) delay -= step;
    }
  }

  void _stopHolding() {
    _holding = false;
  }
}
```

Here it is in action:

[image: The hold-to-increase control]

Comment: Very good answer, thank you very much!

Comment: Tried all three, this is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

To improve [Elte Hupkes's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69977924/18883651), I fixed an issue where the number of clicks and the number of calls to the `onUpdate` callback did not match when tapping consecutively.

`_tapDownCount` variable is additionally used.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// A round button with an icon that can be tapped or held
/// Tapping the button once simply calls [onUpdate], holding
/// the button will repeatedly call [onUpdate] with a
/// decreasing time interval.
class TapOrHoldButton extends StatefulWidget {
  /// Update callback
  final VoidCallback onUpdate;

  /// Minimum delay between update events when holding the button
  final int minDelay;

  /// Initial delay between change events when holding the button
  final int initialDelay;

  /// Number of steps to go from [initialDelay] to [minDelay]
  final int delaySteps;

  /// Icon on the button
  final IconData icon;

  const TapOrHoldButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.onUpdate,
      this.minDelay = 80,
      this.initialDelay = 300,
      this.delaySteps = 5,
      required this.icon})
      : assert(minDelay <= initialDelay, "The minimum delay cannot be larger than the initial delay"),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _TapOrHoldButtonState createState() => _TapOrHoldButtonState();
}

class _TapOrHoldButtonState extends State<TapOrHoldButton> {
  /// True if the button is currently being held
  bool _holding = false;
  int _tapDownCount = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var shape = const CircleBorder();
    return Material(
      color: Theme.of(context).dividerColor,
      shape: shape,
      child: InkWell(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Icon(
            widget.icon,
            color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline1?.color ?? Colors.white70,
            size: 36,
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () => _stopHolding(),
        onTapDown: (_) => _startHolding(),
        onTapCancel: () => _stopHolding(),
        customBorder: shape,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _startHolding() async {
    // Make sure this isn't called more than once for
    // whatever reason.
    widget.onUpdate();
    _tapDownCount += 1;
    final int myCount = _tapDownCount;
    if (_holding) return;
    _holding = true;

    // Calculate the delay decrease per step
    final step = (widget.initialDelay - widget.minDelay).toDouble() / widget.delaySteps;
    var delay = widget.initialDelay.toDouble();

    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay.round()));
      if (_holding && myCount == _tapDownCount) {
        widget.onUpdate();
      } else {
        return;
      }
      if (delay > widget.minDelay) delay -= step;
    }
  }

  void _stopHolding() {
    _holding = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**USING SETSTATE**

You can achieve this by simply "*onLongPressStart*" and    "*onLongPressEnd*" properties of a button.
In case you can't find "*onLongPressStart*" / "*onLongPressEnd*" properties in your widget, wrap your widget with the    "**GestureDetector**" widget.

```
GestureDetector(
  child: ..,
  onLongPressStart: (_) async {
    isTap = true;
    do {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
    } while (isTap );
  },
  onLongPressEnd: (_) => setState(() => isTap = false),
);
```

}