# How can I increase the speed of my text animation in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm trying to increase the speed of my change in text by pressing a button. So my text is a `number.toString()` and is increasing by 1 (++) every time I click my `GestureDetector` that I've created. But I'm trying to use the property `onLongPress` to increase the speed by which my text increases when I hold the button down. But nothing I've tried has worked successfully!

I've scoured the internet for info and all I found was how to slow it down one by one, which is not only the opposite of what I need but also it doesn't continue decreasing in count when I hold down the button, it only decreases the speed at which the button is pressed per number. The code I used was:

```
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
```

...

```
Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

children: <Widget>[

GestureDetector(onTap: () => age >= 100 ? null : setState(() { 
age++; }),

child: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline, size: 40.0, color: 
Colors.white,),

onLongPress: () { setState(() {
timeDilation = 10.0;
weight++;
}); 
},
), //GestureDetector
```

I expected the animation time to decrease, but I didn't expect to have to repeat tapping the button each time to allow for this decrease. I really want to increase the animation time and keep it increasing without having to constantly repeat pressing the button.

Comment: Can you show more or less an example of what you’re trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `onLongPress` in the `GestureDetector` is used for longer taps, it's still designed for a single press, not for contnual presses. What you're looking for though can be accomplished with the `Listener` widget, using `onPointerDown`, which would allow you to continuously process a tap down. [There's a simple example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52132799/5720160).