# IconButton and long press detection

Tags: android, flutter

Please help me with long press detection on an icon button.

I'm trying to get an icon button that will change the quantity value by 1 if tapped and by 10 while long pressed.
The problem is that there is no a long press event handler available for the `IconButton` in Flutter 2.12 unfortunately.

So I used just the `Icon` inside the `Container` as below

```
        GestureDetector(
          child: Container(
            child: const Icon(
              Icons.add,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 18.0),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            increment(1);
          },
          onLongPressStart: (_) async {
            startPressing(() => increment(10));
          },
          onLongPressCancel: () {
            cancelPress();
          },
          onLongPressEnd: (_) {
            cancelPress();
          },
        ),
```

it is working but the problem is that press area is very small and it is uncomfortable to find a press point while on the mobile.

I've tried to increase the icon size to 48 but the result is awful the icon is unnatural big

```
const Icon(
              Icons.add,
              size: 48,
            ),
```

the design that looks fine for me is to use the `GestureDetector` (for long press) with `IconButton` (and onPressed for single tap detection):

```
        GestureDetector(
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () => decrement(1),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.remove,
            ),
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0, horizontal: 18.0),
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          ),
          onLongPressStart: (_) async {
            startPressing(() => decrement(10));
          },
          onLongPressCancel: () {
            cancelPress();
          },
          onLongPressEnd: (_) {
            cancelPress();
          },
        ),
```

is it fine for Flutter to have the `GestureDetector` for longPress and the `IconButton` for onPressed ?
May I have some trouble on some specific Android version with such solution?

Comment: When you fire `onPressed` it will fire `onLongPressEnd ` also, try to add `print()` to see what happen

Comment: @cahyo everything  is working fine. My question is "is it safe to put IconButton over the GuestureDetecor" ?

Comment: I find it ok. Not the most elegant, but it works for me and is readable.

Answer (score 3):

Try with `InkWell` instead, it will act like `IconButton` and gives you ripple effect

```
Material(
  child: InkWell(
    onTap: () {},
    onLongPress: () {},
    child: Ink(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: thanks but it has the same problem - only icon reacts on tap (or long press). It may be fixed with `Ink (padding)` but another problem is still here. `GestureDetector` allows to increment value by 10 while long tap was started until   `onLongPressCancel` or `onLongPressEnd` . However `InkWell( onLongPress` fires only once.

Answer (score 1):

set up `width` and `height` to `Container` and put into `GestureDetector` and fix size by padding of `Icon`

```
     Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      width: 40, 
      height: 40,
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Padding(
         padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 18.0),
         child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
      ),),
      onTap: () {
        increment(1);
      },
      onLongPressStart: (_) async {
        startPressing(() => increment(10));
      },
      onLongPressCancel: () {
        cancelPress();
      },
      onLongPressEnd: (_) {
        cancelPress();
      },
    ),
   )
```

Comment: this is working if `child: Padding(` is removed from the widget controls hierarchy. With `Padding()` both `onTap` and `onLongPressStart` is not working at all

Comment: padding is child of `GestureDetector` it can't disable parent's actions

Comment: probably but I've tried your sample next to working `IconButton` before first comment was written. The `GuestureDetector` does not work with `Padding` child (and it works when `Padding` is removed)

Answer (score 0):

Custom icon button. Based on the answer of cahyo.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LongPressIconButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function() onPressed;
  final void Function() onLongPressed;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final IconData iconData;
  final Color color;
  final double? iconSize;
  final String? tooltip;

  const LongPressIconButton(
      {super.key,
      required this.onPressed,
      required this.onLongPressed,
      required this.width,
      required this.height,
      required this.iconData,
      required this.color,
      this.tooltip,
      this.iconSize});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Tooltip(
        message: tooltip ?? '',
        child: InkWell(
          customBorder: new CircleBorder(),
          onTap: onPressed,
          onLongPress: onLongPressed,
          child: Ink(
            width: width,
            height: height,
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            child: Icon(iconData, color: color, size: iconSize ?? 24),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use like:

```
  LongPressIconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            increment(1);
          },
          onLongPressed: () {
           increment(10);
          },
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          height: 60,
          width: 60,
          iconData: Icons.plus_one,
          tooltip: 'Increment',
        ),
```

Comment: I do not have a chance to check but will it continue to increment while user holds finger on icon? The answer from cahyo does not provide such possibility and onLongPressed fires only once

Comment: It fires only once.  Just checked on Android and the web.

Comment: @oleksa. You can be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52128572/flutter-execute-method-so-long-the-button-pressed